# How to assign pipeline result to a variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to assign the "running time" of a script to a variable "realtime". So I tried as below:

```
realtime = `{ time (echo "mirror -Rv $LocalPath $LocalPath";echo "quit";)|lftp -u s1238262 FTPS://$RemoteHost ; } 2>&1 |grep "real"| awk '{print $2}'`
echo $realtime
```

But I got a error:

```
++ grep real
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ realtime = 0m2.403s
./test.sh: line 6: realtime: command not found
+ echo
```

I tried

```
realtime = `{ time pwd; } 2>&1 |grep real|awk '{print $2}'`
```

It did work. But the ftp script did not. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless you have a function or alias named `realtime` defined in your interactive session, I suspect the `realtime = ...` invocation did not work. Variable assignments in `bash` require that there be no space either between the variable name and the `=` sign, or after the `=` sign and before the value (e.g. `realtime=something` is good, `realtime =something`, `realtime= something` and `realtime = something` all are not good).

Comment: Also `grep foo | awk '{bar}'` is usually better written `awk '/foo/{bar}'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But about the re-writing of awk, I did not get it. I wrote it as ``realtime=`{ time pwd; } 2>&1 |awk '/grep "real"/{print $2}'` ``. But it ran to error:
`++ awk '/grep "real"/{print $2}'`
`+ a=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must not be spaces around the `=` in bash.

```
result=`ls`
```

Comment: [Don't parse ls though!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). (Sorry, couldn't resist :-) )

Comment: Cheers! I haven't used to the "no-space" rule of bash.